# Проблема после удаления файлов из списка отслеживаемых (git)

Tags: git

Кратка история:

- сперва отслеживал гитом изменения в директории image и коммитил их
- позже решил, что хочу исключить директорию из списка отслеживаемых
- добавил правило /image/* в .gitignоre и вызвал команду git rm --cached -r image/

Все работает отлично до тех пор, пока я не переключусь на один из предыдущих коммитов, где image ещё отслеживалась. После checkout на старый коммит, git восстанавливает прежнее состояние файловой системы (в том числе и директорию image). Но после возвращения на рабочую ветку, полностью чистит директорию image, за исключением тех файлов, которые я добавлял после git rm --cached -r image/.

Comment: Это вы так решили поиздеваться над Git? А какого поведения вы ожидали?

Comment: Как правильно исключить директорию image, чтобы все работало корректно?

Comment: Я ведь написал, что добавил каталог в .gitignore. Мне нужно оставить директорию image в текущем состоянии, но удалить файлы в ней из списка отслеживаемых. И так, чтобы git не удалял их при переключении между коммитами.

Answer (score 1):

.gitignore тоже имеет версию.

Назовите директорию по другому.